# Making Threaded Rails?

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to create basically one cylinder going into another cylinder like a bolt/nut, but have the outer cylinder be more of a tube. So the inner cylinder is short like the nut, the idea is to have the inner cylinder be able to slide freely through the outer cylinder.

I need it to move 4.75mm into the outer cylinder per 90 degrees of rotation. So I don't think the same thread pattern as a bolt/nut will work. It might be more accurately like a gun barrel pattern, but the bullet meshes with grooves of the barrel. Sorry I don't really know the terminology.

Here's a general idea of the model, except the tube is suppose to have the grooves as well.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick but imperfect solution:

Duplicate this object and use both Relative and Object offset to create a longer sort of... drill bit type object that maintains the rotation you want.

[image]

Then use *Boolean Modifier to subtract the inner object from the outer.

[image]

This does leave some internal faces that need to be removed, I haven't figured out how to prevent that.  *Merge* option won't do it for me.

[image]

After cleaning up the top two 'ribs'.

[image]